# Hadoop bashrc files

Tags: bash, hadoop

I am installing a second version of hadoop on my computer and want to create a second .bashrc file for the configurations. For one version, I just called it .bashrc. For the second one, do I name it hadoop-2.4.1.bashrc or .bashrc-hadoop-2.4.1? Or would hadoop be installed correctly either way?

Comment: I'm not sure if `hadoop` reads `.bashrc-hadoop-2.4.1` but why not create another user for it anyway?

Comment: By creating another user do you mean something like, for example on Mac, creating another admin in "Systems Preferences"?